# Infinitesimal orbit type decomposition of Hamiltonian $G$-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, group-actions, hamiltonian-mechanics, moment-map

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group acting in a Hamiltonian fashion on a symplectic manifold $M$ with momentum map $\mu:M\to \mathfrak{g}^\ast$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. Then several standard textbooks (for example Ortega–Ratiu: [*Momentum Maps and
Hamiltonian Reduction*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-3811-7) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2021152))) treat the stratification of the symplectic quotient
$$
M//G:=J^{-1}(0)/G
$$
by orbit types $(H)$ of the $G$-action: 
$$
M//G=\bigsqcup_{(H)}(M//G)_{(H)},\qquad (M//G)_{(H)}=M_{(H)}/G,
$$
where $M_{(H)}=\{p\in M: \exists\, g\in G,\; G_p =gHg^{-1}\}$, $G_p$ being the isotropy group of the point $p$.

Now, there is also a decomposition of $M//G$ by infinitesimal orbit types:
$$
M//G=\bigsqcup_{(\mathfrak{h})}(M//G)_{(\mathfrak{h})},\qquad (M//G)_{(\mathfrak{h})}=M_{(\mathfrak{h})}/G,
$$
where $M_{(\mathfrak{h})}=\{p\in M: \exists\, g\in G,\; \mathfrak{g}_p=\operatorname{Ad}(g)\mathfrak{h}\}$, $\mathfrak{g}_p$ being the isotropy algebra of the point $p$.

If $G$ is the circle group $S^1$, then this decomposition is a stratification and is described, for example, in Lerman–Tolman: [*Intersection cohomology of $S^1$ symplectic quotients and small resolutions*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1092749399) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1758240)).

However, I could not find a reference in which the infinitesimal orbit type decomposition (or indeed stratification?) is considered in the general case. Which is a good textbook or paper on this subject?